# How to change a key(index) of a value in an associative array?

Tags: tcl

I need to alter the key in an array.

```
array set sports {
    {dhoni} cricket
    {nadal} tennis
    {messi} football
}
```

Expected array after altering the key:

```
array set sports {
    {dhoni} cricket
    {federer} tennis
    {messi} football
}
```

I need to alter the key of tennis from `nadal` to `federer`

Answer (score 4):

You need 2 lines:

1. Set the new key

   ```
   set sports(federer) $sports(nadal)
   ```
2. Remove the old key

   ```
   unset sports(nadal)
   ```

Comment: is it anyway possible that new key would overwrite the old one without having to execute unset command.

Comment: no. you could do an `array get`, change the key, followed by `unset` the entire array and then `array set`, but in this case you still need `unset`